# How to get an image source using pygelbooru?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm at my wits end. I don't understand what I'm doing at this point. Here is a link to the library: https://pypi.org/project/pygelbooru/

Comment: Show us the code you have already tried, and tell us what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was confusing for me too at the start but it can be done like this.

```
n = 1
results =  your grlbooru function
for result in results:
    url = str(results[n])
    print(url)
    n = n+1
```